# Django Forms with different attributes linked to the same Django Model?

Tags: python, django, forms, development-environment

I'm pretty new to Django so forgive me if my code isn't too refined and the questions seems confusing.

I'm attempting to make a web app where users can submit application forms for licenses. My problem is that there are different kinds of application forms.

I've created a model for Licenses and included global attributes such as License ID, Licensee, and Submission Date and Expiry Date. I'm wondering how I can store the different data unique to each form (for instance, some forms have file upload fields while others don't) in a single License object. Is this possible, or should I create different models for each form?

Here's some of my code:

#models

```
class License(models.Model):
licensee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
sub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
exp_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.exp_date = self.sub_date + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    super(License, self).save()

def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

#forms

```
class OP100Form(ModelForm):

financial_statements = forms.FileField()    
annual_report = forms.FileField()           
shareholding_docs = forms.FileField()
stock_exchange_docs = forms.FileField() 
other_docs = forms.FileField()          
tel_experience = forms.CharField()
tech_facilities_desc = forms.CharField()
tech_personnel_desc = forms.CharField() 
system_maintenance_desc = forms.CharField()
telcoms_desc = forms.FileField()
serv_desc = forms.CharField()
fac_desc = forms.CharField()
net_gate_det = forms.CharField()

class Meta:
    model = License
    exclude = ['licensee', 'sub_date', 'exp_date',]
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to create another model. What to do is this.

Any field that is not required in the `License` model, set `null=True, blank=True` on the field.

Any field that is not required on the form, set `required=False` on the field.